# Label that turns into textbox when clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Maybe there is a CSS style for this, but, I want my TextBox to look like a label. When it is focused, I want it to look like whatever CSS style is applied. I am using bootstrap so that would be the style.

Is there some way to do this?

I have a grid view that I want to allow the user to rename without using the Edit Mode.

Thanks

(EDIT)

I mean an editable label:
see http://dotnetspeaks.net/post/exm/EditableLabel.aspx

Comment: You mean like taking the border off the TextBox?

Comment: Probably should show an example in jsfiddle.net or something (two textboxes, before and after?) you can use `input:focus{}` though to change it, is that what you're after?

Comment: The borders and the background yes, but only when not focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a wild guess (since the question itself is a bit vague):

```
input {
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
}
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

And, [voila!](http://jsfiddle.net/drVVf/) (and a version that [more traditional](http://jsfiddle.net/drVVf/1/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use textbox by making it appear label and making it textbox on click or on focus. (just an approach, question is bit confusing.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function TextBox2Label()
{
    var control=document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
    control.style.borderStyle="none";
    control.style.backgroundColor="Transparent";
    control.style.fontStyle.fontColor="Black";    
    control.readOnly=true;
}        
</script>
```